# Joining pandas dataframe with sql table for efficient select statement

Tags: python, sql, pandas, data-extraction

Imagine a sql-table called `fruits` with the following data

```
id    name   color
1   apple     red
2   apple   green
3  orange  orange
4  banana  yellow
```

In python this can be created in memory by

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import pandas as pd


# create engine in memory
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
conn = engine.connect()


# define table
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class Fruits(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'fruits'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    color = Column(String, nullable=False)

# create db
Base.metadata.create_all()

# insert data
fruits = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['apple']*2 + ['melon'] + ['banana'],
    'color': ['red', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']
})
conn.execute(Fruits.__table__.insert(), fruits.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Now I want a method `get_fruit_id(df)` that returns ids from the table based on the `df` input. So with `df` given by

```
color   name
red     apple
green   apple
yellow  melon
```

I'd like `get_fruit_id(df)` to return something like `(1, 2, NaN)` or

```
color   name    id
red     apple   1
green   apple   2
```

One possible solution is to extract all data from the fruits table and use pandas.merge, but I'm going to work with large tables so I'd performance is much prioritized. Extracting all data seems unnecessary to me.

The example using df can easily be created by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['apple']*2 + ['melon'],
    'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
})
```